# fullcalendar newevent in a new window

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I've managed to have fullcalendar working as I wanted. However, I wanted to implement a new functionnality.

When clicking on the calendar in agenda view, I am redirected to a new page, where I can create an event with the information I require. Not a popup, as I have lots of informations linked to events. I use it as a reservation system for clients.

So I use this : (within my javascript  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ ... )

```
selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    window.open("index.php?n=new_event_admin&start="+start)
    },
```

This works fine, but not exactly as I want.

1. It opens on click in a new window, it does not reload within the same window.
2. I am expecting a date format of : 13.01.2014 08:30 but instead I'm getting Tue Jan 14 2014 13:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time).

Should I modify : window.open("index.php?n=new_event_admin&start="+start) and somehow modify the start variable (how ?).

Can someone please explain or show me where I can get this information.

I've searched within the documentation of http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/ but I didn't find anything. Maybe I over looked an article ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refresh a current window you can call a function say mylocation()

```
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {

       mylocation(start,end,allDay);
   },
```

and can pass params according to your need. it will refresh the current location.

```
 function mylocation(start,end,allDay)
  {
    window.location.assign("/index.php?start"+start)
  }
```

Basic example you can find here
     [Basic Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_assign)

Comment: Thanks for the example, I see what you mean. However, should I edit the variable start before the user clicks or on the second page, once it loads. In order to have the variable output something like :
1. 17.02.2014 09:30
instead of :
2. Mon Feb 17 2014 09:30:00 GMT 0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
jQuery('#fullCalendar').on( 'click', '.fc-event', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
window.open( jQuery(this).attr('href'), 'New Window','width=' + window.outerWidth+',height=' + window.outerHeight );});
```

Where #fullCalendar is div tag of calendar and "New window" is the name of the window title.

You can also add the below code to full calendar declaration

```
    eventClick: function(event) {
    // opens events in a popup window
    window.open(event.url, 'new window', 'width=700,height=600');
    return false;
    },
```